# How to refresh a customized view in a layout

Tags: android, view, invalidation

I just created a view for displaying PDF file

```
    public class PDFGraphic extends View{
     String mText;
     float mLastX;
     float mLastY;
    public float mOffX;
    public float mOffY;
    Canvas mCan;
    Bitmap mBi;

    public PDFGraphic(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){ 
        super(context,attrs);
        setPageBitmap();
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    public void uiInvalidate() {
        postInvalidate();
    }
    public void setPageBitmap() {
        mBi = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.RGB_565);
        mCan = new Canvas(mBi);
        mCan.drawColor(Color.RED);
        }
   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
             canvas.drawBitmap(mBi, 0, 0, paint);
        }
}
```

And this is my xml file(pdfview):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="bottom|center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minHeight="30px" android:visibility="visible">
        <com.shawnprojectPDF.PDFGraphic android:id="@+id/pdfview1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_height="match_parent"></com.shawnprojectPDF.PDFGraphic>
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/leftarray" android:id="@+id/left" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginLeft="68px"></ImageButton>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:gravity="center" android:width="100px" android:singleLine="true" android:maxLength="12"></EditText>
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/right" android:src="@drawable/rightarray" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my main activity,if setContentView(R.Layout.pdfview), the view(PDFGraphic) will not be invalidated, if setContentView(New PDFGraphic(this)),it invalidates successfully.
How to refresh the view in the whole layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. These are the results that I get with your code (next time, you do this part). With `setContentView(R.layout.pdfview)`, this is the result:

[image: setContentView(R.layout.pdfview)]

With `setContentView(new PDFGraphic(this, null)` -- note that I used the two-arg constructor because you didn't define PDFGraphic(Context) -- this is the result:

[image: new PDFGraphic()]

In either case, your `onDraw()` is happening correctly.